# Why use Nullable.Value if HasValue = true

Tags: c#, nullable

Is there any reason why I should use Nullable.Value instead of the underlying variable? i.e. is there any reason why I should use #1 or #2 below?

```
decimal? Quantity = 5;

if(Quantity.HasValue)
{
    System.Console.WriteLine(Quantity); // 1
    System.Console.WriteLine(Quantity.Value); // 2
}
```

Comment: Yes: what if it does not have a value?

Comment: In *this* case perhaps not. In methods that require `decimal` though you *can't* pass a `decimal?`. You also can't use decimal's methods like the [ToString()](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.decimal.tostring(v=vs.110).aspx) overlaods through a `decimal?` reference

Comment: @rbm I'm not sure how it can happen so "it does not have a value" *and* "HasValue=true" at the same time...

Comment: the .Value is the Non-nullable version of the variable for easier use.
int? i = null;
i = 1;
int j = i.Value;